# Automating deleting <Deleted Contacts> folder on outlook.com website

Tags: javascript, outlook

I have 100k+ contacts in the deleted folder of https://outlook.live.com/people/0/

These do not show up on the PC outlook software that is connected via exchange.

They don't show up on any app on the Android mobile that is also connected to this account.

Nonetheless I'm trying to empty this folder.

The webpage only lets 50 contacts to be deleted at an instance so the option of highlighting all the contacts and clicking delete is greyed out when choosing more.

I tried using chrome developers tool to modify this limit but cannot find a way.

Another alternative would be to automate highlighting 50 contacts and pressing the delete button.

I have tried:

```
for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
var xpath = "//span[text()='Delete']";
let results = [];
let query = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

length = query.snapshotLength;
for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) { console.log(query.snapshotItem(i).id); }

console.log("Length: "+ length)
console.log("Clicking");
query.snapshotItem(0).click()
console.log("Clicked");

query = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

length = query.snapshotLength
for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) { console.log(query.snapshotItem(i).id); }

console.log("Length: "+ length)
console.log("Clicking");
query.snapshotItem(2).click();
console.log("Clicked");
}
```

which works once but stops.

Any kind heart able to help on this or give pointers.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, I found that the output of this part:

```
console.log("Length: "+ length)
console.log("Clicking");
query.snapshotItem(2).click();
console.log("Clicked");
```

Was:

> Length: 2
> VM543:20 Clicking
> VM543:22 Clicked

Which then threw an exception:

> VM474:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click') at :21:26

When I changed that line to

```
query.snapshotItem(1).click(); // the second element
```

It executed the command.